# How do I bundle a C program with auxiliary data files?

Tags: installation, package

I apologize if this question is a repost. It seems like it ought to be
but I'm having an extremely difficult time finding a solution on the web.

I wrote a C program that needs to read in some auxiliary files during
its operation. I typically just put these files in the same folder as
the compiled executable, and then just load these files using a
relative path.

However, this only works if the user's working directory is the same
as the folder where the executable is stored. This is insufficient for
my purposes, as I want users to be able to call this executable from
other directories.

What is the standard way of packaging programs that span more than a
single executable binary? The program is meant to be used by near
computer-illiterate people, and I am looking for the closest to a
point-and-click solution possible.

Thanks very much.
  -Patrick

---

Thanks very much for the replies! That gives me a starting place to look. I'll google around for determining the executable path for each OS.

Comment: This question is very dependent on your operating system, both for how you package a program and for where you should place files your code needs to see.

Comment: It's not about packaging, but about finding the executable path in order to reference it from within the program. And the way to do it depends on the OS.

Comment: @EugeneSh. However on some OSs you just don't put data files in the same directory as the executable in the first place. I bet people would not be happy if their `/usr/bin` had a bunch of data files in it.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yeah, that's a consideration.

Comment: Can you bundle the data into the executable itself? Windows has *resources* for this; on Linux, you can still include them as arrays.

Comment: As for where to properly think about putting them, look at [**FHS - Filesystem Hierarchy Standard**](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) which is a good attempt at standardizing file locations (on Linux)

Comment: you still can put your files in the same folder where executable is and detect full path to executable in runtime, so you will be able to find out folder

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your operating system. Windows has things called resources (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7.aspx) for this which allow you to bundle files with the executable. Perhaps the easiest way to do this on any platform would be to include the data in an array. If you need to edit make changes to that data at runtime you could add identifiers to the array (something like `char Data[] = {'I','D','E','N','T',/*your data*/,'I','D','E','N','T','1'}`) and then find that array in the binary at runtime and change its contents. I know that is a very bad solution, but it might just work.